# What is the appropriate value of network connection timeout Android

Tags: android, networking, timeout, network-connection

I'm using the facebook's library [network-connection-class](https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class). This library classified the network connection into 4 quality: Poor, Moderate, Good, Excellent.
My applications usually fetches images from server.  What is the approriate networkTimeout value for each network quality? I'm using OkHttp of Square for http client.
Besides that there are also readTimeout and writeTimeout parameter. Are they the same as networkTimeout?

Comment: can't see how to do this :(